# NodeJS `net` module slow ECONNREFUSED on Windows

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

There seems to be a huge performance difference between Linux and Windows when handling errors on the `net` module of NodeJS. I was handling an `ECONNREFUSED` error on Windows which seemed to be almost **85 times slower** compared to Linux.

Take a look at the following scratch file:

```
const net = require("net");
console.time("Timing");
const connection = net.createConnection(9999, "localhost");

connection.on("error", err => {
    console.log(err);
    console.timeEnd("Timing");
});
```

#### The result of running this file on Windows 10 Pro 64bit:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9999
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1126:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9999
}
Timing: 2030.534ms
```

Note the timing here is `2030.534ms`.

#### The result of running this script on WSL

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9999
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9999 }
Timing: 24.748ms
```

The timing here is `24.748ms`.

Why is this performance gap so big? Can anyone elaborate on what happens internally when executing above script and what could possibly case the difference in performance?

---

**Edit**
I checked out which versions of Node I'm running to be able to compare the two:
*Windows:* `v12.11.1`
*WSL:* `v10.16.3`

I'm running WSL2 on Windows 10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363

To be sure this issue occurs on the same version of node I upgraded node in both environments to `v12.14.1`. Windows was still a lot slower than WSL. Here are the results for the test:

#### Windows:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9999
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9999
}
Timing: 2038.687ms
```

#### WSL:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9999
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9999
}
Timing: 18.661ms
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally i don't see any difference

WSL running ubuntu in ZSH

```
➜  networkPerf node app1.js
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9999
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9999
}
Timing: 1072.149ms
➜  networkPerf node -v
v12.13.1
```

Windows cmd prompt

```
StangerD@laptop c:\_stuff\code\playground\node\networkPerf
$ node app1.js
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9999
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9999
}
Timing: 1057.658ms
StangerD@laptop c:\_stuff\code\playground\node\networkPerf
$ node -v
v12.13.1
```

Things I would check

- Versions of node are the same
- versions of your dependencies are the same
- There are no services running on port 9999

Also what version of wsl are you using in on wsl1 windows 10.0.17134 Build 17134
Also do you see any differences when using ip 127.0.0.1 instead, maybe its a slow name resolution issue?

Comment: I changed the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` but Windows was not faster.
 I did figure I was running another version of node on WSL but I upgraded node in Windows and in WSL and ran the tests again. Updated the question with the new results.